# When I open my Acra Library app, it crashes

Tags: android, acra

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", // will not be used
//http://demo.ivdisplays.net/lms/crasher/crasher.php
formUri = "http://demo.ivdisplays.net/lms/crasher/crasher.php")
public class AppController extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        isloggedin = 0;
        try 
        {
            super.onCreate();
            mInstance = this;
            ACRA.init(this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        //ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
        //settings = Common.getInstance();
        //settings.attachToContext(this);

    }
}
```

Here is the logcat error

> 11-15 18:28:49.995 28883-28917/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
>   Thread-2315 Process: com.purple.lms2,  PID: 28883
>   java.lang.InternalError:  Thread starting during runtime shutdown at 
>   java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method) at 
>   java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063) at 
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.enableConnectionGC(AbstractConnPool.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.createConnectionPool(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:125)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:103)
>   at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.getHttpClient(HttpRequest.java:214) at
>   org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:141) at
>   org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225) at
>   org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179) at
>   org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141) at
>   org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)

Comment: Try again with an up-to-date version of ACRA

Comment: Please tell the process how to update it.

Comment: Just update the version in your build.gradle

Comment: Please tell me the updated version

Comment: `'com.faendir:acra:4.10.0'` (newer) or `'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'` (official)